# Area of a Dodecagon

Tags: geometry, area

The distance between two opposite vertices of the dodecagon is 2. Find the area of the dodecagon.

[image]

Comment: Note: Please DO NOT use trignometry.

Comment: Found: it is $3$. What's my prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigonometry is the right way, but to avoid it, you can proceed as follows . . .

Take one the $12$ isosceles triangles.

Draw an altitude from one of the base vertices to the opposite side.

The altitude splits the isosceles triangle into two right triangles, one of which is a $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangle with hypotenuse $1$.

Since the altitude is the side of the $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangle opposite the $30$ degree angle, its length is half the length of the hypotenuse, hence is equal to $1/2$.

So now you can find the area of the isosceles triangle (area = $\frac{1}{2}bh$).

To finish, just multiply by $12$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:[image: Dodecagon!]
Now all you have to do is find the side length in terms of the distance from the center to the outside (Pythagorean theorem should help with that).

Comment: Nice construction!

Comment: Here's another cool one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817594/429987